# Java - Trouble Joining Tables

Tags: sql, database

I am working with a sql database that has 3 tables. Country, City, And CountryLanguage.

The query string I create contains data that is in all 3 of the tables.

I have no problem linking the Country to the City database using a join statement. Ex. `SELECT Country.Name FROM City INNER JOIN Country ON Country.Code = City.CountryCode WHERE City.Name ='Abakan'`. But I am having a huge problem trying to get to the Language database using a join statement.

To me using this statement: `Select CountryLanguage.Language FROM City INNER JOIN CountryLanguage ON City.CountryCode = CountryLanguage.CountryCode WHERE City.Name ='" + theCity + "'");` should work.

All the databases have CountryCode (or in come cases 'Code') In common. Yet I still cant acces CountryLanguage. When I actually hardcode in a query string to connect to COuntryLanguage It works great. But I need the query string to be dynamic.

Thanks!

Comment: Print the value of theCity in debug & if its proper try trimming theCity.trim()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the quotation marks? Depending on your platform, the string quotes may automatically be added.